# Run C and C++ on VS Code (and even a little problem with vs code bars)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

i have some problems:

1. i cant run c and c++ on vs code (or, i mean im trying by adding the path of MinGW on env vars, but no results by typing on cmd gdb --version, but i have by typing g++ --version)
2. [aaand i just hided this bar by mistake, how to adjust? thanks to everyone!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SdEw.png)

Comment: Add the tools to your PATH; it was likely in any setup instructions you read or the installer itself. Also, where are you getting minGW; there are good and bad places. I can't immediately help with the Activity Bar, but the View menu is a good place to start, with the settings json next.

Comment: oh thanks, i just didn't know the name of that bar, that was the problem, i'll try to fix the c and c++ problem and all will be perfect :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Add to the path variable the directory of the bin folder of MinGW.
Ex: `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`

2- Check that your Mingw-w64 tools are correctly installed and available, open a new Command Prompt and type:
`g++ --version`
OR
`gdb --version`

3- Create helloworld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

4- Save

5- From the main menu, choose `Terminal > Configure Default Build Task`. In the dropdown, which will display a tasks dropdown listing various predefined build tasks for C++ compilers. Choose `g++.exe build active file`, which will build the file that is currently displayed (active) in the editor.

[image]

This will create a `tasks.json` file:

6- To run the code:

- Save helloworld.cpp
- press Ctrl+Shift+B or from the Terminal main menu choose Run Build Task
  You should see this in the terminal:

  [image]
- Create a new terminal using the CTRL + SHIFT + ~
- In that new terminal type: `.\helloworld.exe` to run the code

Reference: [C++ in VS-code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)